# Voltage across a capacitor in a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

[image: Circuit diagram]

I'm trying to find the voltage across the capacitor when it is fully charged in the attached diagram, I haven't done a problem like this before and I'm quite confused on what I am supposed to do to find the voltage.
Am I supposed to find the voltage across each resistor first?

Comment: Perhaps this question should go here? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

"Am I supposed to find the voltage across each resistor first?"

Yes, that's a good first step. [The quick way is to treat the left and right resistor combinations as *potential dividers*.] Note that the capacitor itself might as well not be there. It is fully charged so no current is flowing on to or off its plates.

Then you need to recall that voltages are *potential differences*, and that these are analogous to height differences. So, bearing in mind that the lower resistors are connected together at their bottom ends, which are therefore at the same potential, you can find the potential difference between their top ends, that is the potential difference across the capacitor.

[Suppose that point P is 10.8 m above ground level and point Q is 4.0  m above ground level. What is the height difference between P and Q ?]